# How can I generate pagination when looping through pages rather than posts?

Tags: php, wordpress-theming, wordpress

Essentially what I need is to generate the equivalent of, if this were a blog layout, the nav-below nav-previous link that's default in the 2012 theme... which I believe uses the function:
**next_posts_link();**

I kind of need a  **next_PAGES_link();** or something. it's a "onepage" layout. I'm not in charge I just have to figure out how to make this happen and I'm out of ideas.

If there isn't a function that groups pages together and returns them as a single page- I need to make one and I'm not a php expert... something like:

```
>>grab list of pages from database,
>>group pages into array pageGroup- each group of pages in pageGroup contains (x) number of pages
>>return each pageGroup item as a WordPress page.
>>generate link to new the next pageGroup WordPress page at the bottom of every pageGroup page.
```

Answer (score 0):

Read a bunch at https://codex.wordpress.org/Pagination

The Bones theme by Themble has an entire custom built code base for their own pagination function. Its awesome and easy to use. I would study that as well in Bones theme ->library-bones.php. Here's a quick manipulation I came up with from the codex that is untested but correct in logic:

```
$args  = array(
    'paged' => paged,
    'posts_per_page'  => 5, //-1 shows all
    'post_type'       => 'page',
    'suppress_filters' => true
);

$posts = new WP_Query( $args );

if ( $posts -> have_posts()) {

<!-- Add the pagination functions here. -->

    while ( $posts -> have_posts() ) : $posts->the_post();  {

    //do stuff with the posts returned here
    }

    <?php endwhile; ?>
    <!-- End of the main loop -->
    <!-- Add the pagination functions here. -->

    <div class="nav-previous alignleft"><?php next_posts_link( 'Older posts' ); ?></div>
    <div class="nav-next alignright"><?php previous_posts_link( 'Newer posts' ); ?></div>

    <?php else : ?>
    <p><?php _e('Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.'); ?></p>
<?php endif; ?>
}
```